# Calculating a large haversine distance matrix

Tags: python, cuda, nvidia

Ran OOM trying to calculate a haversine distance matrix on a list of geocoordinates. I have access to a GPU which can fit the distance matrix but I can't find any libraries with haversine distance matrix implemented for GPU. Looking for advice on writing a CUDA kernel for this.

Comment: What is large? And do you need the full matrix or only the closest few, within radius, or other condition?

Comment: The size of the resulting distance matrix in my case is 6GB when represented in float32 precision. The distance matrix is used as input to a clustering algorithm which does not support the haversine distance metric.

Comment: Alternatively, there are clustering methods that do offer custom distance metrics, e.g. k-medoids.

Comment: 6GB should be doable, before puah to GPU rethink calculation/inplementation. Jumping to hardware/platform changes is last resort with scaling or make something faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading into numba's cuda library and NVIDIA Rapids, I was able to create the following Python function:

```
from numba import cuda
import math

@cuda.jit
def gpu_haversine_distance_matrix(lon, lat, dm):
  i,j = cuda.grid(2)
  if i < lon.shape[0] == dm.shape[0] and j < lat.shape[0] == dm.shape[1]:
    if i == j:
      dm[i][j] = 0
    else:
      if i < j:
        longit_a = math.radians(lon[i])
        latit_a = math.radians(lat[i])
        longit_b = math.radians(lon[j])
        latit_b =  math.radians(lat[j])
      else:
        longit_a = math.radians(lon[j])
        latit_a = math.radians(lat[j])
        longit_b = math.radians(lon[i])
        latit_b =  math.radians(lat[i])
        
      dist_longit_add = longit_b - longit_a
      dist_latit_sub = latit_b - latit_a
      dist_latit_add = latit_b + latit_a
      pre_comp = math.sin(dist_latit_sub/2)**2
      area = pre_comp + ((1 - pre_comp - math.sin(dist_latit_add/2)**2) * math.sin(dist_longit_add/2)**2)
      central_angle = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(area))
      radius = 3958
      dm[i][j] = math.fabs(central_angle * radius)

co_loc_cdf = cudf.from_pandas(co_loc) # pandas dataframe containing longitude and latitude column
dm_global_mem = cuda.device_array((co_loc_cdf.shape[0], co_loc_cdf.shape[0]))

threadsperblock = (16, 16)
blockspergrid_x = math.ceil(co_loc_cdf.shape[0] / threadsperblock[0])
blockspergrid_y = math.ceil(co_loc_cdf.shape[0] / threadsperblock[0])
blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y)
haversine_gpu_distance_matrix[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](co_loc_cdf['longitude'], co_loc_cdf['latitude'], dm_global_mem)
```

This returns a haversine distance matrix in GPU memory. The unit for distance is measured in miles but the `radius` value can be adjusted to return meters if so desired. Would still appreciate knowledge on how to best decide the threads per block and blocks per grid.